# Can we squash jquery-[\d.-]+ back into plain jquery?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

jQuery released a new version, so someone created a tag for it. Is that really necessary?

[jquery-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-2.0) was [created circa '13](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16130331/revisions), and since then it was used on no more than 27 questions. 23 of them are already tagged with [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery). It's plainly obvious that whatever version of jQuery you are using, you are still using jQuery. Can we keep the same analogy for our tags?

The blog post announcing the release hints that the version numbering doesn't imply a total remake of the implementation of the library:

> Despite the 3.0 version number, we anticipate that **these releases shouldn’t be too much trouble when it comes to upgrading existing code**. Yes, *there are a few “breaking changes” that justified the major version bump*, but we’re hopeful the breakage doesn’t actually affect that many people.

Which is kind of what the Linux kernel did for their 3.x release, when Linus just didn't want to continue the 2.16 branch.

Comment: The usual guidance for such tags is that you use the master tag, and then you add the version-specific tag *if your question has to do specifically with something in that version.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's inaccurate: [I would only use version tags when the question content is irrevocably tied to a specific version of something and **can never be relevant to earlier versions or later versions**.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744/213575) jQuery has high backwards compatibility, so, we expect that additions of the 3.x branch should be usable on later branch, as 2.x and 1.x features are available on 3.x

Comment: @Braiam Isn't the quote exactly what Robert said?

Comment: @Rob no, because Robert is normally read as *"as long as you are using that version"*, mine means *"that if the issue you are facing isn't present in later nor earlier versions"*.

Comment: @Braiam I disagree, it doesn't say as long as you are using that version, it says if the question has to do with something in that specific version. I.e. That version is part of the cause of the problem.

Comment: I'd weight in here, but apparently I said something different than I thought I did.

Answer (score 6):

Version-specific tags should be used when a question is about a something that's in a specific version of a library.

Both the master tag and the version-specific tag should be used, then.

Comment: "Both the master tag and the version-specific tag should be used, then." Why have 2 or more when a single one does the job, *very well*?

Comment: Tagging only the version specific tag means the question won't be visible to users keeping an eye on the master tag.

Comment: Because your opinion that a single tag does the job _very well_ isn't shared by the majority @Braiam, or so it would seem from the reaction to this question. People seem to disagree that a question specifically about jQuery 3 is clearer/clear enough without a jquery-3 tag, than with one

Answer (score 4):

The generally accepted practice regarding version tags would mean that if something has a [jquery-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-n), then it should *also* have [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery). Regardless of that version number `n`. So if you find a question which only has a version tag, add the base tag as well.

As for the version tag, it doesn’t get useless just because it’s never used on its own. You should use a version tag if there is a question which is related to a specific version.

Of course it’s not always clear to judge whether that’s the case (especially for OP), so another somewhat accepted practice is to use the version tag to specify what version one is using. For example with the Python version tags, you’d tag your question with [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) if you are using Python 2, so answerers know that they don’t need to give Python 3 specific answers (and vice-versa).

So, the bottom line is, yes, the tag might not be that super useful considering that there won’t be that many changes in jQuery 3. However that does not invalidate the version tag, so the answer to the question in your title would be: No, we shouldn’t just squash all versions into the main tag since version tags still have their place for certain situations.

Comment: The situations create the tag, nor backwards. The situation do not merit a new tag.

Comment: Questions about functionalities from specific versions of software should be tagged with the software's version. Those situations _do_ merit a new tag.